# Initialize C++ objects once in JNI/Android

Tags: android, opencv, java-native-interface, instantiation

I am new to Android and JNI stuff. But well experience in C/C++. I am trying to figure out the following

Porting a desktop code made in VS2013 to Android. This is an opencv project.
I have ported most of the performance code.
But I am unable to understand how to initialize some objects and keep them alive during the life time of a certain processing step.

Pseudo-code of desktop code

```
vector<contours*> cntrs // Initialized somewhere else

void ProcessFrame(Mat)
{

    LOOP until kb != 'q'
    {
         step 1 - Extract contours and add them to vector<contours> 

         step 2 -  Display contours
    } 
}
```

In android, I understand that I can pass an image to C/C++ code process it and then throw it back to Java.
But what I want is that I do not want to initialize the vector every time I enter my main JNI function that will extract contours.

Is there a well defined way/pattern/technique of doing this.

Any answers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global objects in your C++ are legal. You can use some special JNI call to initialize them, or rely on the JNI specific JNI_OnLoad() which is guaranteed to be called once after your native code (shared object, the Android analog of Windows DLL) is loaded. You can also let the compiler take care of this initialization, e.g.

```
std::vector<int> global_v  { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 };
```

**Update**: there is another related design pattern, when a JNI call returns (usually as **long**) an oblique *handle* (actually, a native pointer) to a native object, and this handle is further used in all JNI calls that correspond to this object. The handle is dereferenced by C++ to the actual native object, and all processing involves this. Here is an example:

**Java**

```
package com.demo;
public class FILE {
  public void test1 {
    long file = fopen("/sdcard/test1", "w");
    fputs(file, "abc");
    fclose(file);
  }

  static { System.loadLibrary("FILE"); }
  private static native long fopen(String fname, String fmode);
  private static native long fwrite(long f, String s);
  private static native void fclose(long f);
}
```

**C++** (compiled with NDK into libFILE.so)

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_demo_FILE_fopen(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jstring fname, jstring fmode)
{
   char *szfname = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, fname, 0);
   char *szmode = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, fmode, 0);
   FILE* f = fopen(szfname, szmode);
   (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, fmode, szmode);
   (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, fname, szname);
   retrun (jlong)(f);
}

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_demo_FILE_fputs(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jlong jf, jstring s)
{
   char *szs = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, s, 0);
   FILE* f = reinterpret_cast<FILE*>(jf);
   long len = fputs(f, szs);
   (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, s, szs);
   retrun len;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_demo_FILE_fclose(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jlong jf)
{
   FILE* f = reinterpret_cast<FILE*>(jf);
   fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: So what you mean to say is that I can keep them as globals then make a JNI call to initialize them. But a better is to call JNI_Load()? In that case I still keep them global?

Comment: I am sorry that my answer was confusing. Yes, in any case you keep global objects global, because the usually JNI call scope is short time, and sequence of JNI calls does not share some specific C/C++ context.

Comment: There is no universal "better" in decision whether to use JNI_OnLoad() or a proprietary JNI call, or a global scope initialization. The choice depends on the nature of your program. Use of proprietary JNI initializer gives your Java **better control**, e.g. allows to re-initialize the object at your will, even if the library is not loaded again. But if you don't need such control, the other two options are **better** in the sense that they do not require an additional Java call.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Solves a confusing issue. I will try this out. Cheers

Comment: I understood the benefit of the C++ `std::vector` to avoid the hassle of manual resource de-allocation. However, I cannot use this because my JNI is to load an  apriori unknown size binary data  ~90MB.  Hence, I have to `malloc or new`. At present, the only I find is `onPause / onResume` as my C/C++ constructor / destructor entry points. I don't like it, but what can i do...

Comment: @typelogic: with `std::vector` you don't need the hassle. You have a global vector object, when the data arrives, you resize it and fill it; you can resize it and fill with different data (even of different size) at any time. When its time comes, it will be released by the C++ runtime.